# Fundamental group of a solid torus with a tunnel?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Imagine that you have a donut and a worm inside. This worm takes two turns around the solid torus, going back to the starting point after two laps. How could I find out what the fundamental group of this space is? Can I use Van-Kampen's theorem to solve it or maybe exact sequences? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to be more precise with your description. The fundamental group should depend how the path is knotted.

Comment: The space that i'm referring to is a donut without the tunnel that the worm creates. This tunnel starts in a point inside the solid torus, takes a turn arond the interior of the donut, but don't ends in the starting point, because it takes another turn around the donut. The worm never goes through the same place during the two laps.

Comment: Right, but the path could twist around itself and give a nontrivial knot. If the knot is homotopic to the knot that just passes around the core circle of the donut, it should follow some pretty standard knot theory (I assume) that the fundamental group is the same as if you just removed the core. This space is homotopy equivalent to a torus, so you can calculate its fundamental group.

Comment: Yes but I think the knot is not homotopic to the knot that just passes around the core circle of the donut. If I had a connected tunnel that takes 1 turn around the donut, the torus would be a retract of the space. But I think it's not my case. It's like if you had a rubber band and you twist it to having two circunferences (really aren´t circles, It's an example), and I think is not homotopic to a circumference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I call $A$ the space that you are talking about. $A$ is of the form $A=\Lambda-T$ where $\Lambda$ is the original donut, and $T$ is the "tunnel" (it is a specific subspace of $\Lambda$ homeomorphic to a torus). I claim that $A$ deforms retract onto a subset $X$ such that

$$X\simeq \Bbb T^2 \bigsqcup \Bbb M^2/\sim$$

where $\Bbb M^2$ is the mobius band and $\sim$ is the relation attaching the boundary of $\Bbb M^2$ along one "canonical generator" of the fundamental group of the torus $\Bbb T^2$. The space $X$ is just "a mobius band which has his usual boundary replaced by a torus". To see that, I did the following drawing:

[image]

In my drawing, the big torus $\Lambda$ is in green, the tunnel $T$ created by the worm is in red and $X$ is the union of $T$ and the hatched grey mobius band. The mobius band is created by drawing the lines as in the picture.

In order to understand that $A$ deforms retract onto $X$, think of it the way around. If you take a neighborhood of $X$ in $A$, it looks just like $A$.

The only thing left to do is to compute the fundamental group of $X$. The space $X$ can be seen as follows, with the identifications by colors:

[image]

I don't know what is the best way to compute $\pi_1(X)$. Here is two ways that I can think of:

- You can use the "classic trick" that consists in doing a hole in the space and then using Van Kampen to get the fundamental group of the original space. To be more precise, take a disk $D^2\subset X$ and $p\in D^2$. Then if $\gamma$ is a generator of $D^2-\{p\}$ and if $i:D^2-\{p\}\to X-\{p\}$ is the inclusion, the theorem of Van-Kampen implies 
  $$\pi_1(X)\simeq\pi_1(X-\{p\})/_{\langle i_*(\gamma)\rangle}$$
- More interestingly, in the picture we see $X$ as the quotient space 
  $$X= Y\times [0,1]/_{Y\times 0 \stackrel{\varphi}{\sim} Y\times 1}$$ where $Y$ is two circles joined by a straight line and $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism that "turns $Y$ upside down". This is perfect to use the *quotient* version of Van Kampen. This version is not very famous, and the [only reference](http://analysis-situs.math.cnrs.fr/Theoreme-de-van-Kampen-version-fermee.html) I have for it is in French (but it's actually a great reference if you can understand French, there is a very comprehensive video going with it!).

I'm sure there is some alternative ways to compute $\pi_1(X)$. Anyway using the first method I found 
$$\pi_1(X)\simeq \langle a,b~\vert~ bab^{-2}a^{-1}b=1\rangle.$$

In my opinion, this was not obvious at all, I can add details/drawings if needed. But I feel that you should give it a try using Van Kampen now that the situation is more clear!

I hope this helps!

**Edit:** I added some detail changed the names of the spaces (the previous names were implicitly saying that $\Lambda$ and $T$ had dimension 2 instead of 3)

**Edit 2:** As smartly suggested by Kyle Miller in the comments, there is an easy way to compute $\pi_1(X)$. If $a$ and $b$ are two generators of the torus such that $X$ is obtained by identifying the boundary of the mobius band with $a$, and if $c$ is a (well chosen) generator of the fundamental group of the mobius band, the theorem of Van Kampen gives

$$\pi_1(X)\simeq \langle a,b,c~\vert~ ba=ab,~c^2=a\rangle,$$

which can be rewritten

$$\pi_1(X)\simeq \langle b,c~\vert~ bc^2=c^2b \rangle,$$

which is the same as in the other presentation.

Comment: What is the classic trick you mention?

Comment: @ConnorMalin when you have a surface $S$ you do a hall in it, i.e you consider the space $S-D^2$. You compute the fundamental group of this space, usually using deformation retraction. Finally you compute $\pi_1(X)$ with Van Kampen by looking at the morphism induced by $i:S-D^2\to S^2$.

Comment: Will this morphism always be surjective, is the kernel usually easy to compute?

Comment: @ConnorMalin it depends, you have to look closely in each case. I did a little mistake the morphism that you have to look to is induced by $\partial D^2\to S-D^2$.

Comment: And how do you do to compute the relations −2−1=1?

Comment: @josmat have you tried to do a hole and use Van Kampen?  What I have is that $X-D^2$ deforms retract onto the wedge sum of a mobius band and a circle, so it has fundamental group  $<a,b>$ for some canonical generators $a$ and $b$. Then I try to write $\partial D^2$ (I mean the path associated to it) as a combination of $a$ and $b$. I found $bab^{-2}a^{-1}b$, I can do a drawing if you want. Also is the deformation retraction of $\Bbb T^2-T^2$ onto $X$ clear for you?

Comment: Okey, thanks!!! It's all clear for me. But I have a last question, which would be the fundamental group of the manifold obtained joining the two bounds of A?

Comment: So you want to identify the torus "inside" of $A$ and the torus "outside" of $A$ ? This makes me think that my notation is really bad, because $\Bbb T^2$ is 3-dimensionnal and not two-dimensional as suggested by the index. I'll edit the post later.

Comment: @josmat Identifying the inside and outside tori likely depends on which identification you use (there is an $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$'s worth).  Maybe it's worth asking that as a separate question.

Comment: @AdamChalumeau You can use the van Kampen theorem with a torus and the Mobius strip from your picture (the space is a torus $S^1\times S^1$ with the boundary circle of a Mobius strip glued in along $S^1\times *$).  Call $a,b$ the generators of each circle for the torus and $c$ the generator for the Mobius strip.  Then the group is $\langle a,b,c \mid ab=ba, a=c^2\rangle$, which is isomorphic to $\langle a,c \mid c^2b=bc^2\rangle$.

Comment: @KyleMiller oh yes you're right we can do this as the boundary of the mobius band is connected. And it is very simple to compute like this, probably the best way. Well done!

Comment: @KyleMiller I added this solution to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is Adam's second approach in more detail.

The space in question is a nice example of what is called a *mapping torus*.  We have a surface $\Sigma$ which is a disk minus two disks (a "pair of pants"), and then we can construct the space as a quotient
$$X=\Sigma\times [0,1]/((f(x),1)\sim(x,0))$$
where $f:\Sigma\to\Sigma$ is a homeomorphism from swapping the holes by dragging them around while keeping the outer boundary fixed:

[image: The map f used for the mapping torus construction]

Through the van Kampen theorem, one can show that $\pi_1(X)$ is $\pi_1(\Sigma)\ *_{f_*}$, which is what is called an HNN extension.  Concretely, the group has the presentation
$$\pi_1(X) = \langle \pi_1(\Sigma),t\mid tgt^{-1}=f_*(g)\text{ for all }g\in\pi_1(\Sigma)\rangle.$$
The $t$ generator (the *stable letter*) corresponds to a loop that goes around in the $[0,1]$ direction of $X$. (See Example 1B.13 in Hatcher for more about mapping tori and HNN extensions, where the two homomorphisms are $\operatorname{id}$ and $f$.)

The following illustrates the computation of $f_*$, using the fact that $\pi_1(\Sigma)=\langle a,b\rangle$ is a free group on two generators:

[image: The action of f on the generators of the fundamental group]

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\pi_1(X)&=\langle a,b,t\mid tat^{-1}=b, tbt^{-1}=bab^{-1}\rangle \\
&=\langle a,t\mid t^2at^{-2} = tat^{-1}ata^{-1}t^{-1}\rangle \\
&=\langle a,t\mid tat^{-1}at^{-1}a^{-1}ta^{-1} \rangle.
\end{align*}

(If $L$ is the link [L4a1](http://katlas.org/wiki/L4a1), then $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^3-\nu(L)$, where $\nu(L)$ is a thickened-up $L$, a *tubular neighborhood*.  This is not the unique link whose complement is homeomorphic to $X$: basically, you can twist the holes in $\Sigma$ around any odd number of times and get the same space!)

Comment: Nice! Do you know if the theorem giving the fundamental group of $X$ in terms of the one of $\Sigma$ and $f$ is given a name like "quotient version of Van Kampen" by some authors?

Comment: Also I think it is interesting to point out that there is an explicit isomorphism between our presentations, given by taking $a^\prime=a$ and $b^\prime=ta^{-1}$ as the new generators (in this case your relation becomes mine).

Comment: @AdamChalumeau Hatcher Chapter 1 exercise 11 gives it as an exercise, and gives a hint to start with $\Sigma\vee S^1$ and attach cells.  Section 1.B is about fundamental groups of graphs of groups (Bass-Serre theory), which is one way to imagine mapping tori. Brown's "Topology and Groupoids" has a version of the van Kampen theorem for fundamental groupoids, and it handles quotients just fine (page 335 has HNN extensions).  I may have heard of something by the name "quotient version of the van Kampen theorem" before, but I couldn't find it in any of the usual books.